# Is it okay to use Scoped Service inside Singleton?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection

Is it okay practice to pass a **Scoped** `IServiceProvider` to a **Singleton**?

Context is I have a **Singleton `IMediaLibraryObservable`** which has internal List of Observers. This is to trigger hooks such as OnAdding, OnDeleting, etc.

The Observers are interfaces which can implement what they want and re-use registered services. For them to have access to what they need, a **Scoped** `IServiceProvider` is passed as part of the methods.

Code is below:

**Startup Registration:**

```
services.AddSingleton<IMediaLibraryObservable<MediaEventInfo>, MediaLibraryObservable>();
```

**The Interface Observable:**

```
public interface IMediaLibraryObservable
{
    Task OnAdding(IServiceProvider _serviceProvider, MediaEventInfo info);
    ...
```

**The Implementation of OnAdding:**

```
public async Task OnAdding(IServiceProvider _serviceProvider, MediaEventInfo info)
        {
            foreach (var observer in observers)
                await observer.OnAdding(_serviceProvider, info);
        }
```

**The Observer implementation:**

```
public async Task OnAdding(IServiceProvider _serviceProvider, MediaEventInfo info)
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await info.File.CopyToAsync(ms);
                var path = await ServiceProviderHelpers.GetService<IBlobStorage>(_serviceProvider).WriteAsync(info.ContentItem.InternalName, ms);
```

**Trigger of Observable (*where scope IServiceProvider is passed into Singleton observable*):**

```
private readonly IMediaLibraryObservable _mediaLibraryObservable;
private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

public MediaLibraryService(IMediaLibraryObservable mediaLibraryObservable, IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
  _mediaLibraryObservable = mediaLibraryObservable;
  _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
}

public async Task < bool > UploadBlob(string fullPath, FormFileDto file) {
  ...
  await _mediaLibraryObservable.OnAdding(_serviceProvider, info);
  ...
}
```

Comment: It is okay to *use* a Scoped Service inside Singleton, as long as you don't *store* that scoped service inside the Singleton, as that would lead to a [Captive Dependency](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/).

Comment: Thanks Steven, the link is great as well!